# Tomcat Realm used with Jasypt and SHA-256

Tags: java, tomcat, jasypt

I create new users who can log into my Java EE application using Jasypt to hash the password: I use SHA-256, an 8 bytes salt, 1000 iterations and get an 80-character hexadecimal hash in the database. This is working. Here is the code:

```
ConfigurablePasswordEncryptor passwordEncryptor = new ConfigurablePasswordEncryptor();
SimpleDigesterConfig config = new SimpleDigesterConfig();
config.setAlgorithm( "SHA-256" );
config.setIterations( 1000 );
config.setSaltSizeBytes( 8 );
passwordEncryptor.setConfig( config );
passwordEncryptor.setPlainDigest( false );
passwordEncryptor.setStringOutputType( "hexadecimal" );
String hashedPassword = passwordEncryptor.encryptPassword( password );
```

Then I store it in the DB.

Now, in my DataSource Realm, I'm trying to tell Tomcat what I am doing like this:

```
<Realm 
        className="org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm"
        name="monRealm"
        dataSourceName="jdbc/postgres"
        localDataSource="true"
        userTable="users" userNameCol="login" userCredCol="password"
        userRoleTable="user_roles" roleNameCol="role_name"      
        debug="99">

        <CredentialHandler className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MessageDigestCredentialHandler"
                      algorithm="SHA-256"
                      iterations="1000"
                      keyLength="256"
                      saltLength="8"
        />

</Realm>
```

In my opinion, this is the same thing. And the Realm should check the password just fine.

But I never manage to log in with the login/password I have created. It works without the hash part, so this is really the way I hash the password that is wrong. But I can't see where I missed something.

Thanks in advance for you help!

Answer (score 0):

You almost certainly have to massage the information coming out of your `ConfigurablePasswordEncryptor`.

Try running this command. You can see how Tomcat expects stored-credentials to be formatted in the user database:

```
$CATALINA_BASE/bin/digest.sh -a SHA-256 -i 1000 -s 8 'test password'`
test password:d2ff2cb07d35c790$1000$13a74a8c198db73981f0a596c1e21421596afd0ca446dfb857d3c524604e8781
```

Note that the "test password" is hashed, but the stored credential also stores the value of the salt and the number of hash-iterations being used. If `ConfigurablePasswordEncryptor` does not format its output in the same way, you will need to arrange for that to happen.

There is another option: you can arrange for Tomcat to use your own credential-handling code by implementing your own `CredentialHandler`. Have a look at this presentation for [how to write your own CredentialHandler](http://people.apache.org/~schultz/ApacheCon%20NA%202017/Seamless%20Upgrades%20for%20Credential%20Security%20in%20Apache%20Tomcat.pdf). See slides 21-22, and 33-39. Read the whole thing, actually, but those slides should be able to get you started if you want to use the exact same code to generate *and* verify your stored passwords.